# Spring Security jsf - login form redirects to the same login page after successful logging

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security, annotations

Here is my **login.xhtml**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:panel id="panel" header="Connexion">
            <p:messages id="msgs" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                <h:outputLabel for="login" value="Login: *" />
                <p:inputText id="login"
                    value="#{utilisateurAuthentificationService.login}"
                    required="true"
                    label="Login">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="login" display="icon" />

                <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password: *" />
                <p:password id="password"
                    value="#{utilisateurAuthentificationService.password}"
                    label="Password" required="true">
                    <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
                    <p:ajax update="msgPassword" event="keyup" />
                </p:password>
                <p:message for="password" id="msgPassword" display="icon" />

            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton id="btn" value="Connexion" update="panel"
                actionListener="#{utilisateurAuthentificationService.authentifierUtilisateur(utilisateurAuthentificationService.login,utilisateurAuthentificationService.password)}" />
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here is my **security-config.xml**:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config='true'>


        <intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome.xhtml*" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <form-login login-page='/login.xhtml'
            always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="utilisateurService">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

The spring security filters in **web.xml**:

```
<!-- Spring Security filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

After successful logging **instead of** redirecting me to the **welcome.xhtml** page (which is by the way the welcome file specified in web.xml), it redirects me to **login.xhtml** page...

Where is the problem? Is security-config.xml misconfigured? or is it something else?

Please tell me if I have to show you some ohter code details..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling csrf protection here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf

Or try adding he CSRF token: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-form

Comment: It says "Our recommendation is to use CSRF protection for any request that could be processed by a browser by normal users. If you are only creating a service that is used by non-browser clients, you will likely want to disable CSRF protection." So why disabling it while my authentication request will be processed by a browser by normal users ??

Comment: @Siho OK, I updated the answer, could you try to add csrf token? +1 for your comment :D

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
ajax="false"
```

to your command button so it looks as follows :

```
<p:commandButton id="btn" value="Connexion" update="panel"
            actionListener="#{utilisateurAuthentificationService.authentifierUtilisateur(utilisateurAuthentificationService.login,utilisateurAuthentificationService.password)}" ajax="false"/>
```

I'm not entirely sure why this works, but I think it's because the button now does a full page submit instead of an ajax request which allows Spring Securitys redirect since it's no longer a partial page rerender.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding default-target-url="/Welcome.xhtml" attribute to form-login element like